# Runtime button is going under the form object

Tags: c#, object, runtime, hide

What I want to do is creating a button at runtime. But I want to show that on the `ListBox`. I create a button but it is going under the `ListBox`. The `ListBox` is hiding the button.

Comment: Pick a better Location or call the button's BringToFront() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Control.BringToFront`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx) to move the button above the other controls.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked
Note: You must add that code after this.Controls.Add(control) code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
yourButton.BringToFront();
```